# Necessary condition for selecting a New coordinate system (as tangent and normal vectors)

Tags: calculus, vectors, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

I wanted to understand intuitvily, how it is possible to make tangent and normal vectors as a coordinate system for a planar motion because my concern is that what I have read about coordinate system is that once it is fixed along a particular direction after that those directions will remain same regardless of  curve for example Cartesian coordinate

but

My concern with tangent and normal as coordinate system is that it keep changing for every new curve because tangent and normal for every other curve will be somewhat different which is quite unintuitive to what I have read earlier about coordinate system .

Can anyone clear my doubt ,what is basic criteria for selecting a coordinate system ?

Answer (score 0):

```
my concern is that what I have read about coordinate system is that once it is 
fixed along a particular direction after that those directions will remain 
same regardless of curve for example Cartesian coordinate
```

That paragraph is where things go wrong, or at least where your confusion is revealed.

Let's think about a curve $\gamma$ in the plane. We have, for each $t$, the point
$$
\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))
$$

For instance, if $x(t) =  t$ and $y(t) = t^2$, the curve described by $\gamma$ is a parabola. It's made up of many different points, one for each possible $t$-value. The fact that $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ doesn't prevent $\gamma(2)$ from being $(2, 4)$, right? If we think of $t$ as "time", then you could say that we have a "continuously changing point" moving along the curve, but in reality, we have many many points, each attached to a particular time-value. $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$, and it never changes, but $\gamma(t)$, as $t$ varies, **does** change.

The same thing is true for coordinate systems: the cartesian coordinate system is fixed once and for all. For our curve, the tangent vector at time $0$ is $[1, 0]$, and the normal is $[0, 1]$. That tangent-normal pair is fixed for all time. But at time $t = 1$, the tangent is $[1, 2]$ and the normal is something like $[-2c, 1c]$ for some value of $c$ that I'm not going to compute. We can use either of those to measure things like "the position of $\gamma(2)$".

The clever idea of the "moving frame" is that in measuring things associated with $\gamma(t)$, for some particular $t$, it may be useful not to use $T(0), N(0)$, or $T(1), N(1)$, but instead to express things in the coordinate system $T(t), N(t)$.

We do this all the time in real life. Imaging you're driving a car in the US; your friend Robin is in the passenger seat to the right of you. Your child is in a car-seat right behind you. You start out driving North, so Robin is to the East of you, but soon the road curves and you're driving East, and Robin is to the south of you. But in your mind, we ignore the global N/S/E/W coordinates, and you say "the whole time I was driving, Robin was to my right, and my child was behind me". In this case, you're using, at each moment, a coordinate system based on the car's orientate *at that moment*, i.e., a constantly moving frame-of-reference.